# C# and context menu of windows explorer

Tags: c#, wpf, regedit

I tried to add an item to context menu of the Windows Explorer (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10104/Add-a-context-menu-to-the-Windows-Explorer), and it worked but I still don't know how to get the path of selected files?

I tried `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` but it only returns the path of my application and not the selected files.

Can anyone tell me how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the command to pass the related path.  Instead of using:

```
// From the related article
regcmd.SetValue("",this.txtPath.Text);
```

You should be able to use:

```
string command = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"%1\"", this.txtPath.Text);
regcmd.SetValue("", command);
```

This builds a command string that includes the path to your executable (`this.txtPath.Text`) followed by the selected item used when triggering the context menu (`%1`).